# How to convert unix epoche time into Date in Swift3

Tags: date, type-conversion, swift3, epoch

I want to convert epoche time (number) retrieved from database into a Date Object using Swift 3.

I've got following code for the number

```
// e.g. 1475616846.424875
user.birthday.timeIntervalSince1970
```

How can I convert this in a Date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [reference of `Date`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date):

> ```
> init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval)
> ```
>
> Returns a Date initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 by a given number of seconds.

Simply use the initializer of `Date`:

```
let epochTime: TimeInterval = 1475616846.424875
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: epochTime)
print(date) //->2016-10-04 21:34:06 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3**

This code **solve** the problem for swift 3.

```
func epochToLocal(epochTime:Double)->String{

    let timeResult:Double = epochTime
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeResult)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium //Set time style
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium //Set date style
    let timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier as String
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    return "\(localDate)"

}
```